# Get output date in `31-12-yyyy` format from the `dd-MM-yyyy` value

Tags: sql-server

```
From_date  23-03-2014, 16-06-2015, 28-03-2016,  18-09-2011 
To_date    31-12-2014, 31-12-2015, 31-12-2016,  31-12-2011
```

If I am giving any date `dd-mm-yyyy`, in other column I should get `31-12-yyyy`

I mean the expected `yyyy` will be retrieve from the given date's year.

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to do, the question seems too vague.

Comment: Please go through [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(From_date), 12, 31);

Comment: @RichardHansell I am looking for this solution ,thank u for your valuable time

Comment: @PrabhatG you are awesome!! thats it! I am looking for same only, Thank u so much

Comment: @Rahul : mark it as answer, so that it ll help any one else with similar problem

Comment: @RichardHansell thank u for your simple answer, its very easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following format to change `dd-mm-yyyy` to the expected behavior:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(('28-03-2016'),10),105),101)), 12, 31), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Sample execution with the given data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (TestDate VARCHAR (10));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (TestDate) VALUES 
('23-03-2014'), ('16-06-2015'), ('28-03-2016'), ('18-09-2011')

SELECT TestDate, 
       FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT((TestDate),10),105),101)), 12, 31), 'dd-MM-yyyy') AS ResultDate
FROM @TestTable
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying something like this :

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, cast('23-03-2014' as date)) + 1, -1) AS EndOfYear
```

output : 2014-12-31 00:00:00.000

so try :

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, cast(From_date as date)) + 1, -1) AS EndOfYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare one variable to save From_Date

`DECLARE @From_Date AS DATE = 2014-03-23`

Declare another variable to save only year part of From_Date

`DECLARE @Year_Part AS VARCHAR(4) = DATEPART(yyyy, @From_Date) AS YearOfSelectedYear`

Get last day of selected year

`DECLARE @To_Date AS DATE = @Year_Part + '-12-31'`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, But you should try @Richard Hansell answer. That is the best answer.